# Can I get RavenDB to write to Seq using the NLog WebService target?

Tags: ravendb, nlog, seq

I'm trying to get RavenDB 3.0 log messages into Seq.

Seq supports posting of raw events using JSON: http://docs.getseq.net/docs/posting-raw-events

RavenDB uses NLog for logging. NLog supports a WebService target: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/WebService-target

My attempt so far is this:

```
<target type='WebService'
    name='Seq'
    url='http://localhost:5341/api/events/raw'
    protocol='JsonPost'
    encoding='UTF-8'> 
        <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
            <attribute name='@t' layout="${longdate}" >
            <attribute name='@mt' layout="${message}" >
        </layout>
</target>
```

The full NLog.config file is:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.netfx35.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <target 
            xsi:type="AsyncWrapper"
            name="AsyncLog">

            <target xsi:type="SplitGroup">
                <!-- create log files with a max size of 256 MB -->
                <target 
                    name="File" 
                    xsi:type="File"    
                    archiveAboveSize="268435456"
                    fileName="${basedir}\Logs\${shortdate}.log">
                    <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout">
                        <column name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
                        <column name="logger" layout="${logger}"/>
                        <column name="level" layout="${level}"/>
                        <column name="database" layout="${mdc:item=database}"/>
                        <column name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
                        <column name="message" layout="${message}" />
                        <column name="exception" layout="${exception:format=tostring}" />
                    </layout>
                </target>
                <target type='WebService'
                    name='Seq'
                    url='http://localhost:5341/api/events/raw'
                    protocol='JsonPost'
                    encoding='UTF-8'> 
                        <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
                            <attribute name='@t' layout="${longdate}" >
                            <attribute name='@mt' layout="${message}" >
                        </layout>
                </target>
            </target>
        </target>

         <target 
            xsi:type="AsyncWrapper"
            name="AsyncConflictLog">

            <target xsi:type="SplitGroup">
                <!-- create log files with a max size of 256 MB -->
                <target 
                    name="File" 
                    xsi:type="File"    
                    archiveAboveSize="268435456"
                    fileName="${basedir}\Logs\${shortdate}.conflicts.log">
                    <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout">
                        <column name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
                        <column name="logger" layout="${logger}"/>
                        <column name="level" layout="${level}"/>
                        <column name="database" layout="${mdc:item=database}"/>
                        <column name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
                        <column name="message" layout="${message}" />
                        <column name="exception" layout="${exception:format=tostring}" />
                    </layout>
                </target>
            </target>
        </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <!--<logger name="Raven.Bundles.Replication.Plugins.*" writeTo="AsyncConflictLog" minlevel="Debug"/>-->
        <logger name="Raven.*" writeTo="AsyncLog" minlevel="Trace"/>
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

I'm having problems getting it working - I think my layout is invalid but I'm not getting any errors from RavenDB/NLog so it's very hard to work out what it doesn't like.

**Has anyone done this or can you see what might be wrong?**

Comment: It looks like it's not possible with RavenDB 3.0 as it uses NLog 3.1 and JsonPost was only added in NLog 4.4 http://nlog-project.org/2016/12/14/nlog-4-4-is-live.html

Comment: I think updating to NLog 4.4 could work. Check your internal log for these problems: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging